# Ошибки в Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Конечно извините меня, но я новичок в Kali и меня тревожат две проблемы на которые я немогу найти ответа. Первая - иногда при запуске линукс при загрузке у меня возникает ошибка из-за которой мне приходится перезагружать комп, а именно

> ‘IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready’

И вторая, это когда я нажимаю на кнопку перезагрузки или выключения системы у меня зависает комп. Кто может что подсказать?

Windows 10 x64, Kali installed on Kingston data travel swfv.
Notebook Acer Nitro 5. Hybrid videocards, Intel i7-8700h

Comment: Процитирую официальную документацию: **Kali Linux ориентирована на профессионалов в тестировании на проникновение и аудите безопасности.** Если вы не профессионал в данной области и хотите изучить данный дистрибутив, установите его в VirtualBox и делайте это там. Иначе, это только первые беды с которыми вы столкнулись

Comment: [Документация по дистрибутиву есть на оф.сайте, включая и русский язык.](https://www.kali.org/kali-linux-documentation/)

Comment: [Тут](https://forums.kali.org/archive/index.php/t-37575.html) и [тут](https://forums.kali.org/archive/index.php/t-38867.html) решали уже эту проблему

Comment: Также, если уж сильно интересует именно данный дистрибутив и ты предпочитаешь много "велосипедных решений" вместо простоты и скорости в работе, рекомендую пройти данный гайд: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Просто очень интересует данная область